# XSLT transformation issue : From plain XML to multi level XML

Tags: xml, xslt, bpel

I need to transform below input XML to output XML. Can you please provide any ideas for this.

I need to transform below input XML to output XML. Can you please provide any ideas for this.

Input XML :

```
<GenericCollection ParamValue="ParamValue1" xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <Generic>
    <store>Store1</store>
    <metricName>Metric1</metricName>
    <metricValue>1</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store1</store>
    <metricName>Metric2</metricName>
    <metricValue>1</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store2</store>
    <metricName>Metric1</metricName>
    <metricValue>1</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store2</store>
    <metricName>Metric1</metricName>
    <metricValue>2</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store2</store>
    <metricName>Metric2</metricName>
    <metricValue>1</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store3</store>
    <metricName>Metric1</metricName>
    <metricValue>1</metricValue>
  </Generic>
  <Generic>
    <store>Store3</store>
    <metricName>Metric1</metricName>
    <metricValue>2</metricValue>
  </Generic>
</GenericCollection>
```

**output:**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns4:EnterpriseDocument>
  <ns4:DataSet>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store1">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric2">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store2">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
        <ns4:Data value="2"/>            
      </ns4:Metric>
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric2">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store3">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
        <ns4:Data value="2"/>            
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>     
  </ns4:DataSet>
</ns4:EnterpriseDocument>
    Thanks,
    Ramesh
```

Comment: Is this posted XML is correct? &lt; is here. Have you tried anything to get desired output?

Comment: I tried posting "<" directly and stackoverflow was not accepting it. I dont have much experience in XSLT. I'm using Oracle BPEL XSLT and currently using 3 for-each loop to achieve this. I want to reduce this looping due to performance issues

Comment: Does Oracle BPEL XSLT support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: It wont support during the design time, I mean I cant see the design view of the transformation. However it executes the 2.0 functions during runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, then you should probably be using **xsl:for-each-group** here, rather than **xsl:for-each** because you are trying to group the elements here.

Firstly you are grouping by **Generic** elements by their **store** value, so you would write this.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Generic" group-by="store">
```

Then within this, you would output the **Dimension ** element for the group like so:

```
<Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="{current-grouping-key()}">
```

Next, you want to further group the elements in this group by their **metricName** value

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="metricName">
```

Note the use of **current-group()** here. You are only iterating over the elements in the current "store" group, and not over all **generic** elements.

Finally, to output all your **Data** elements, you would do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.org">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
   <EnterpriseDocument>
   <DataSet>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Generic" group-by="store">
         <Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="metricName">
               <Metric ref_name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <Data value="{metricValue}"/>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </Metric>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
         </Dimension>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </DataSet>
   </EnterpriseDocument>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your XML sample, the following is output (Note, in my sample I am not including any namespaces, just for clarity)

```
<EnterpriseDocument>
   <DataSet>
      <Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store1">
         <Metric ref_name="Metric1">
            <Data value="1"/>
         </Metric>
         <Metric ref_name="Metric2">
            <Data value="1"/>
         </Metric>
      </Dimension>
      <Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store2">
         <Metric ref_name="Metric1">
            <Data value="1"/>
            <Data value="2"/>
         </Metric>
         <Metric ref_name="Metric2">
            <Data value="1"/>
         </Metric>
      </Dimension>
      <Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store3">
         <Metric ref_name="Metric1">
            <Data value="1"/>
            <Data value="2"/>
         </Metric>
      </Dimension>
   </DataSet>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here a xslt-1.0 solution. 
Which does the grouping based on xsl:key ([Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:e="http://www.example.org"
                xmlns:ns4="http://www.exampl.ns4.org">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kStore" match="e:Generic/e:store"  use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="kStoreMetric" match="e:Generic/e:metricName"  use="concat(../e:store,'|', .)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e:GenericCollection">
        <ns4:EnterpriseDocument>
        <xsl:for-each select="//e:Generic/e:store[
             generate-id() = generate-id( key('kStore', . ) [1])
              ]" >
            <ns4:DataSet>
                <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="{.}">
                    <xsl:variable name="s" select="." />
                    <xsl:for-each select="//e:metricName[
                            generate-id() = generate-id( key('kStoreMetric', concat($s,'|', .) ) [1])
                            ]" >
                        <ns4:Metric ref_name="{.}">
                            <xsl:variable name="m" select="."/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('kStoreMetric', concat($s,'|', $m) )" >
                                <ns4:Data value="{../e:metricValue}"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ns4:Metric>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns4:Dimension>
            </ns4:DataSet>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns4:EnterpriseDocument>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<ns4:EnterpriseDocument xmlns:ns4="http://www.exampl.ns4.org" xmlns:e="http://www.example.org">
  <ns4:DataSet>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store1">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric2">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>
  </ns4:DataSet>
  <ns4:DataSet>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store2">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
        <ns4:Data value="2"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric2">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>
  </ns4:DataSet>
  <ns4:DataSet>
    <ns4:Dimension ref_name="bu_code" value="Store3">
      <ns4:Metric ref_name="Metric1">
        <ns4:Data value="1"/>
        <ns4:Data value="2"/>
      </ns4:Metric>
    </ns4:Dimension>
  </ns4:DataSet>
</ns4:EnterpriseDocument>
```